# C# calling native method without allocating memory for required structure parameter

Tags: c#, structure, native, wrapper, managed

I have a **working** C# wrapper class for a native library.
Almost all the native methods are expecting a pointer to structure as a parameter, for example:

```
returntype1 method1(struct1** param1, ...); // yes, there is one method with double reference parameter
returntype2 method2(struct1* param2, ...); // most of the methods expects simple pointer to struct 
returntype3 method3(struct1* param3, ...); // most of the methods expects simple pointer to struct
```

The required structure parameter is defined in the C library header file.

My wrappers are following:

```
[DllImport(LibraryName, CharSet = Charset.Ansi)]
public static extern int WrapperMethod1(ref IntPtr struct1, ...);

[DllImport(LibraryName, CharSet = Charset.Ansi)]
public static extern int WrapperMethod2(IntPtr struct1, ...);
```

What is not clear for me, how can the wrapper even work, when I simply do **NOT** define and use the managed version of the native structure? **But it works!** Tested all the methods and they work exactly as expected.

I simply call them like:

```
var ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
WrapperClass.WrapperMethod1(ref ptr, ...);
WrapperClass.WrapperMethod2(ptr, ...);
```

Why I do not need to allocate memory for the structure using for example Marshal.AllocHGlobal or Marshal.StructureToPtr ? Why it simply works just by specifying a simple IntPtr without any structre defintion and allocation?

Comment: I'm assuming that the C code is allocating memory. `method1` is probably doing something like `*param1 = (struct1*)malloc(...)`. Your `ptr` starts off being `IntPtr.Zero`, but is when modified to point to the memory allocated by the C library. You probably need to be calling a function defined by that same library which releases that memory when you're done

Comment: The unmanaged method must be written to handle NULL pointers to the structs. Presumably the methods then use some defaults, or create the structs themselves and then the marshalling returns the structs via your `ref` parameters. If they allocate the structs, you'll now have a memory leak.

Comment: In the meantime I checked the source code of native methods and as you pointed out, in the method with signature
returntype1 method1(struct1** param1, ...);
there is a malloc( ) call for param1 

and in some other method with signature
returntype2 method2(struct1* param2, ...);
there is a free(param2) call.


So it seems that everything is done by native methods and when I call the first (initialization) method, the marshaling assigns the address of already allocated structure to my IntPtr parameter.